# IAM Role limit sts:AssumeRole to one AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am concerned about security. The creation of IAM Roles is a high security risk, and the fact that you can only specify to be AWS Lambda the one that can assume a role is not good enough IMO. There could be a privilege escalation if not treated with care.

How can I create IAM Roles specific to some Lambda functions?

I haven't found anything similar, but I believe it may be possible.

This role would have also some policies attached:

```
{
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Sid": ""
}
```

Usually, in other roles you would use Principal clause to decide which accounts can assume the role.

```
{
 "Effect": "Allow",
 "Principal": {
   "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:root"
 },
 "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

According to @Michael in the comments, I have to say which users can use pass role on which roles, therefore is the question, how can I decide which users exactly can pass this role?

If so, the answer to this question would be solved in two steps. Making this role only assumable by Lambda service (as it is already), and then have a policy with PassRole restrictions for each user.

Comment: If you don't associate the role with a particular Lambda function (which requires that *you* have permission to do so), then the lambda function can't just "decide" to assume it.   It's not clear why you see a problem here.

Comment: Sure, but the problem I see here is that if I have developers with 2 sets of permissions to develop in AWS Lambda, they may end up gaining privileges by attaching roles they shouldn't to those lambdas. I want to be able to decide which roles can a lambda use.

Comment: You're looking at it backwards.  You grant permission *to the user* to ["pass" specific roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html) to Lambda functions. The decision to be made is which roles a user can pass.

Comment: I have updated the question just to be sure I am asking the appropriate question.  If the question is really like that, I will update the content of the question to make it easy to reference for the future. Please feel free to answer it then

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html#iam-term-service-role

Service roles are intra-account only. So you can restrict it to a single lambda but enforcing that no other lambda in that account assumes that role.

Comment: If you want to improve the security and not have to trust developers to do the right thing you should definitely consider using different AWS accounts for `prod` and `dev` environments.

If you configure your infrastructure with some infrastructure-as-code options (CloudFormation/SAM/CDK) you could easily deploy to different accounts and only give access to these accounts to people that absolutely must have access.

Multi-account strategy is something AWS has been recommending as a best practice, security wise. More info here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqq39mZKQXU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked AWS support about this. They said they don't presently* support conditions in the assume_role/trust policy to limit which functions can assume the role by matching a function name pattern.

Instead, they suggested adding conditions to the execution policy (instead of the assume/trust policy):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "WhitelistSpecificLambdaFunction",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "AROAUISMSUAFHSJDJURKJ:TestLambda"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

> -- This policy denies access to all Lambda functions except the specific Lambda function whose name is mentioned in "aws:userid" condition key. Other Lambda functions will be able to assume the role, but they will be denied from performing any action but if they are just printing or returning any variables/data the function would work.

> --> NOTE: The condition key "aws:userid" specifies the unique ID for the current role and the corresponding value of this key has the following format: "role-id:role-session-name".

> -- IAM role ID is "AROAUISMSUAFHSJDJURKJ" for the sample role I used.

> -- In case of Lambda function the role-session-name is same as Lambda function name. In this example case it is "TestLambda", so aws:userid becomes   "aws:userid": "AROAUISMSUAFHSJDJURKJ:TestLambda"

* They added my name to an existing request to add this feature

Comment: To which object is that *resource policy* attached?

Comment: @mat, presumably the execution role for the Lambda function(s). We haven't tested yet.

Comment: OK. Do you know how I can find out the `aws:userid` of the lambda function?

Comment: @mat see the last paragraph in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to achieve this. If you consider that you need to assign an IAM role to an `AWS::Lambda::Function` on creation, this IAM role needs to exist before the Lambda function does. However, to restrict assume on an `AWS::IAM::Role` to a single Lambda function, the function would need to exist first - you cannot satisfy both conditions.

I am assuming you are creating your infrastructure using CloudFormation here. Perhaps there are ways to achieve this by manually creating your infrastructure in the AWS console, but even if this is possible, this itself is not going to be best practice for sakes of replicability across your environments / regions.

Your security concerns can be mitigated by a combination of:

- AWS CloudFormation drift detection.
- Restricting CloudFormation and perhaps IAM access to a restricted set of developers (e.g team leads).
- As @milan suggests, keeping different environments in different accounts.

The only other option (that doesn't help you) is to restrict the assume of one IAM role to the principal of another role - e.g.:

```
{
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": { "Fn::Sub": "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/role-name"}
  },
  "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

This solution just buries the issue one layer down - you restrict the `sts:AssumeRole` on the role that contains your permissions, but you could still assume this parent role across different lambdas.

*(I know I'm coming back to an old question, but I have been researching something similar around restricting KMS key resources to specific Lambdas when loading encrypted objects from S3.)*

Answer (score 0):

As was already said you can have different accounts for each environment and control who have access to production.

Let's deep in your questions:

1. **How can I create IAM Roles specific to some Lambda functions?** You can define the principal restricting to Lambda service and/or add a condition that uses the key `lambda:FunctionArn` targeting a specific lambda. The drawback is that the lambda must exist before the role as you need its `arn`.
2. **How can I decide which users exactly can pass this role?** Create different groups and choose which groups going to have access to: `CreateRole` and  `Attach*Policy`. Give freedom to devs to `CreatePolicy` but demands policies targetting resources `arn`(again, **Conditions**) or restrict IAM completely to just a group of users responsible for access control and user management.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the answer provided by Steamer25 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64468637), Confirming you still cannot use conditions in the assume role trust policy of an IAM Role, and instead you must use Conditions in the associated IAM Policy documents attached to the IAM Role instead.

After numerous testing of other global condition keys, the aws:userid key is still the most effective method of achieving this. However, to simplify the implementation provided by steamer25, simply use the following:

```
"Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
        "aws:userid": "*:<FUNCTION_NAME>"
    }
}
```

Where <FUNCTION_NAME> is the name of your Lambda Function. The wildcard represents the ID of the IAM Role, but, for the purposes of the condition wildcard works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible that the `*` will allow IAM roles from other accounts?