# How to allow specific AWS lambda the ability to AssumeRole to a specific role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working on aws,
I have a role and 2 lambdas.

I want only those lambdas to run with the role, and the ability to assume role only from those lambdas.

I tried to add the lambdas in the trust relationship of the role and it is not working.

```json
"AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111:root",
        "Service": [
          "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "lambda:FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111:function:service:function_name"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting: `The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda`.

Comment: Don't think you need the `"AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111:root",` in the trust relationship. That said, not sure this is supported. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42717431/iam-role-limit-stsassumerole-to-one-aws-lambda-function

Comment: In the console, under the lambda configuration, you can specify an execution role.  You can also add that to a cloudformation template as part of your lambda deployment.